# How can I check if the notification has been delivered to the intended recipient who is actively connected to the internet using AWS SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to check my notification is triggered or not, when user disallow notification of app. On the App, they are unable to detect when the app is in kill state and can't notify the backend service that message is delivered or not, I want to check, whether my notification is successfully send to device when there is an active internet. Just like whatsapp does

I have impleted AWS SQS service to trigger the notification through SNS using lambda function, but unable to detect the delivery status through code....

Comment: Did you activate [Amazon SNS message delivery status - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-topic-attributes.html)?